# apt upgrade command option not explained in man or --help

Tags: apt, manpage

There is a -u option in this command:

```
apt -u upgrade
```

Can anyone explain what -u option stands here for ?

And why isnt' it explained in the

```
man apt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`apt-get` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get).

> `-u`, `--show-upgraded`
>
> Show upgraded packages; print out a list of all packages that are to
>   be upgraded. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Show-Upgraded.

The command is used to check package to be updated— without actually installing them, the full command would be.

```
apt-get -u upgrade --assume-no
```

However, nowadays it is equivalent to.

```
apt list --upgradeable
```

or

```
apt list -u
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but how come I don't see this information when I type man apt-get in the terminal ?